# Can float (or double) be set to NaN?

Tags: java, floating-point, double, nan

Note: Similar to [Can an integer be NaN in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949457/c-can-int-be-nan)

I understand this has little practical purpose, but can a `float` or `double` be set to `NaN`?

Comment: I wouldn't say there's little practical purpose. For instance I am using this method to specify failed results in a table of doubles.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Float object contains a static value, which is a `float` type, called `NaN`.

So

```
float myFloat = Float.NaN;
```

gives you what you are asking.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#NaN

Comment: I thought that was just a constant representation for a wrapper class (but the constant is still a valid number)? I'm looking for setting the `float` or `double` to NaN, thus making it unusable in any arithmatic.

Comment: No, the constant is for the primitive type.

Comment: Ok, sorry, you edited before I finished this comment, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 12):

Sure!  NaN is a static constant in the Float and Double classes.

```
double x = Double.NaN;
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes

```
float f = Float.NaN;
```

See [the doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#NaN) for more info. Note that if you want to compare a number to NaN, you should use [isNan()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#isNaN%28%29).

Despite your question above, this does have a practical purpose. You can use this to indicate a value hasn't been set/provided yet.

Answer (score 0):

jshell> double ddd=Double.NaN;
ddd ==> NaN

jshell> ddd!=ddd
$5 ==> true