# Spark/Scala : String field is nullable , but a Double field is non-nullable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a DataFrame from RDD, using a case class

I have observed the string fields are appearing nullable and double fields are non-nullable.

Please help me understand this behaviour

PS: I know that field can be made nullable by declaring it as `Option[Double]`, but I wish to understand why this is happening?

```
scala> case class Airport(uuid:String, timestamp:String, iata:String, airport:String, city:String, state:String, country:String, lat:Double, long:Double)

scala> val ap_df = ap_nohdr.map(r => Airport(r(0).trim, r(1).trim, r(2).trim, r(3).trim, r(4).trim, r(5).trim, r(6).trim, r(7).trim.toDouble, r(8).trim.toDouble)).toDF();

scala> ap_df.printSchema
root
 |-- uuid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- iata: string (nullable = true)
 |-- airport: string (nullable = true)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lat: double (nullable = false)
 |-- long: double (nullable = false)
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `ap_nohdr` and explain why you're not just reading that as a Dataset to begin with. For instance, using the CSV reader

Comment: @cricket_007, thankyou for your suggestion, I am aware of directly loading it using a csv reader..   here I am trying it using RDD way. intention is to learn and understand all nuances Spark&Scala offers

Comment: A double is a number. A number cannot be nulled... Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @cricket_007, yes , in those lines..  why a String can be nulled & Double cannot be nulled.. as per my understanding both are scala objects? (or is it not?? , is it a primitive?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Scala `String`, like that in Java, is an object. It can be nulled.

A Scala `Double` is an alias to a Java primitive `double`. It is not a nullable object compared to  `java.lang.Double` (which you're welcome to use in the case class)

You can also refer to this section of the Scala docs on the Null object, which applies to Doubles as well

> Since Null is not a subtype of value types, null is not a member of any such type. For instance, it is not possible to assign null to a variable of type scala.Int.

As you have discovered, the Option class is how you indicate a "nullable primitive"

[scala: assign null to primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168586/scala-assign-null-to-primitive)