# Storing erroneous value in integer

Tags: c++, integer

I have a complete design of my developing software in C++. I **really** do not want to change the structure.

However, I sometimes get erroneous outputs to store in integer variable. Output is not any number, output is NaN. But I do not want to add any other variable to check whether my integer variable is erroneous or not.

Is there any way to store a thing such as NaN in an integer variable?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949457/can-an-integer-be-nan-in-c basically seems to be no.

Comment: You want something like `std::optional` without using it ? There no Nan with integers, so either you can afford the luxury do dedicate a special value for this purpose, or you need to change your interface.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour thank you, I did search but got nothing. I submit close request.

Comment: The only reasonable solution is to use an integer value that isn't otherwise used - `MIN_INT` or `MAX_INT` may be good candidates - or -999999999, 0xDEADBEEF or some other value that is not "a reasonable value for your application" (presumably, since you are using integer values to store floating point results, you are not using the entire integer range?)

Comment: @MatsPetersson, is it safe enough?

Comment: You have to check this special value by yourself, everywhere you may use it. Thus, safety of this solution depends on your own code (or on the code that use you function).

Comment: Safe enough for what? I guess if your floating point calculation can result in "any value", then no - although if it's `float` rather than `double`, you could technically find a value that can't be represented in a `float`. If the results are `double`, not only do you have the problem that all integer values can be represented as integers in a `double`, but you also have integer values that can be WAY outside your integer value (and are precise).

Comment: Basically, even though you do not change the signature of your function, you change the specification (i.e. behavior of it). It is how your propagate this specification change through the whole application that may be unsafe.

Comment: How about throwing an exception instead? Or would that change the structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not magic, it's information theory basics. int is something that stores values in range [INT_MIN, INT_MAX].  That is all it can do, no less no more.

You constrain to use just the int, leaving you the only option to use some value as your indicator. If that is not good enough, you must reconsider the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no value that you can store in an integral type which can represent a `NaN`.

If you need to store this value, you are going to have to reconsider your design.  This doesn't necesarrily mean adding a new variable, but you might change an existing one.  For example, the `int` variable where you currently store this value which can be `NaN` could be changed to something like `boost::optional <int>`.  That way, it could be unset if the value was `NaN`, or set otherwise.

Comment: Someone didn't like this.  I'd love to know why.

Comment: Does optional offer the same performance as an int?