# IsNan() Method Availability

Tags: java, string, methods, integer, nan

In java we can use the `isNan()` method for **float** and **double** values.

E.g.:

```
 if (!Double.isNaN(0.01)) {
     // condition happens    
 }
```

```
 if (!Float.isNaN(0.01F)) {
     // condition happens    
 }
```

I wonder why we can't use it for **Integers**.

Comment: Because integers and strings aren't allowed to take up holy orders? (Sorry, mocking the `isNun` typo).

Comment: You can check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615634/why-doesnt-integer-represent-nan-in-java for more information from a similar question

Comment: @IMSoP The Java, the Sun (Microsystems), and the malformed POST?

Comment: My mistake to ask this question.. :D thank you anyway for clearing the idea..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NaN is [Not a Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), i.e., an undefined or unrepresentible number, such as the square root of -1.
Integers are always well defined, and Strings just aren't numbers at all, so they are irrelevant for checking against being NaN.

Answer (score 2):

Because `String` and `Integer` can't be NaN.

Answer (score 2):

`NaN` is a special value of floating point numbers, along with others like `Infinity`; integers and strings don't have such special values, so the functions to check for them would make no sense.

The reason they exist is to represent the results of certain calculations, so that floating point numbers can be used in arbitrary mathematical situations.