# Why is there no std::copysign specialization for integers in c++?

Tags: c++

I tried using `std::copysign` to set an `int` with the sign of another.

```cpp
int translate = getTranslate();
int offset = getOffset();
translate = std::copysign(offset, translate)
```

But `copysign<int, int>` returns a `double`. 
How should I use it better?
Or what should I use instead?

Comment: Is [`std::copysign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/copysign) really the function you want to use here? It "[c]omposes a floating point value with the magnitude of x and the sign of y", is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! 
I am looking for an alternative to use the sign of `offset` for `translate`.

Comment: So basically something similar to `translate = (offset < 0 ? -std:abs(translate) : std::abs(translate))`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's wrong if `translate` is negative. You need `std::abs(translate)` in the second and third ternary operator arguments.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Ah yes of course, "fixed" my comment. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the alternative! This is also nice to wrap into a template function. The marked answer is a good explanation why there is no `copysign` for `int`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first I was a bit confused about what `std::copysign` is actually good for, but the [note on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/copysign) gives a reasonable motivation:

> `std::copysign` is the only portable way to manipulate the sign of a `NaN` value (to examine the sign of a `NaN`, `signbit` may also be used)

Take this plus the fact that [integers cannot be `NaN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949457/can-an-integer-be-nan-in-c) and it makes sense that there is no `std::copysign` for `int`. On the other hand, a `std::copysign<int,int>` returning an `int` would come in handy in generic code, where you want it to work for `double` as well as for `int`. For this I would perhaps write my own wrapper, starting from a

```
template <typename T> 
T my_copy_sign(const T& t, const T& s);
```

and then specialize it accordingly.

PS: If you are only working on `int`, you probably dont need `std::copysign` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a great explanation and makes sense. I also like that you understood why I need it and why it would be convenient for generic code.

Comment: It has a similar use to abs() and there's actually quite a lot of places where it can be useful to make some other number have the same sign. Here's a simple implementation for signed integers: `template<std::signed_integral IntegerType>constexpr inline IntegerType copysign(IntegerType mag, IntegerType sign) { return (mag < 0 == sign < 0) ? mag : -mag; }`