# Implement NaN for ints in C++17

Tags: c++, overriding, nan, c++-chrono, infix-operator

What would be a C++17 idiomatic way to implement NaN arithmetic for int-like types?  In particular, adding (or subtracting) when either argument is NaN should yield exactly NaN.
(The [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949459/2097284) explicitly excludes ints from such default behavior.  Even `quiet_NaN` returns [zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/quiet_NaN), too dangerous for everyday use.)

My starting point is a value sufficiently out of bounds for my application,

```
constexpr int my_NaN = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

In C, you'd replace each `x + y` with a `my_add(x, y)` which tests x and y against my_NaN.  Ugly.
In Ruby, you might monkeypatch the class Integer with `def +(other) self==my_NaN ? my_NaN : ...`, and blithely `x + y` as usual.
Can C++17 come close to how Ruby lets you preserve conventional infix notation?

---

Besides a bare int, I'm also hoping to do this for
`std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::micro>` and the corresponding `time_point`.  I shudder at overriding all the different ways those can be added and subtracted.

Comment: Define a specific type (class) `nanable_int` and use that.

Comment: You might even then be able to just use `std::chrono::duration<nanable_int, std::micro>` without having to do anything else

Comment: @AlanBirtles, almost.  If `t` has that type, then `t.time_since_epoch() / 1us`, the common way to convert back to bare usecs, needs a custom `operator/`.

Comment: It also needs `operator<`, `operator>`, `operator+`, `operator-`, ... .  Drat.

Comment: Can you just wrap a `double` in a class, and then make sure to floor or ceil or trunc after the appropriate operations?  Still has the "all the operators" problem.

Comment: @Elliott • `double` already has NaN behaviors.  If an `int` is 32-bit on the OP's platform, a double (presumably IEEE 754) can express 53-bit of positive integers with fidelity, and 53-bit of negative integers.  If that 54-ish-bit of range isn't enough, then, yes, a double is not sufficient.

Comment: @Elliot • I'm not sure as to what OP's requirement you are referring to.

Comment: @Elliott: I interpret that statement as "I tried this approach", not as "this is a hard external requirement how NaN must be represented". I agree with Eljay; using FP types as stand-ins for integers is a well-known technique dating back to at least the Cray computers.

Comment: @Elijay, the people have spoken. I've removed my comments. =]